# Error al instalar al crear un proyecto en ruby on rails debido a sqlite3 -v 1.4.0 en Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3

Estoy siguiendo los pasos para empezar con Ruby on Rails y cuando creo un nuevo proyecto me aparece el siguiente error:

```html
   C:\Sites>rails new blog
create
create  README.md
create  Rakefile
...
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Sites/blog/.git/
create  package.json
create  app
create  app/assets/con
....

Installing sqlite3 1.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190213-860-1u87msm.rb
extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Tengo instalado sqlite3 de la version:

```html
PS C:\Sites\ruby\blog> sqlite3 --version
3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56 2ab564bf9655b7c7b97ab85cafc8a48329b27f93
```

Busque mas informacion y no encuentro una respuesta la solucion, en otras respuestas encontre en cambiar a PostgreSQL

Comment: El error es porque no tienes sqlite instalado (o no encuentra las librerías, eso deberías aclarar tu en la pregunta si lo tienes instalado o no). Y sí, postgresql es una mejor opción que sqlite en varios aspectos, pero debes tomar una decisión por cual db engine vas a usar. En caso que decidas irte por potsgresql, cuando crees to proyecto (antes de instalarlo, obviamente), prueba a comenzar con `rails new blog -d=postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar lo que hice fue modificar en Gemfile

```
# Use sqlite3 feas the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
```

por:

```
# Use sqlite3 feas the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

y hacer correr nuevamente

```
>> bundle install
```

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada, click en el check verde del costado, de ese modo colaboras con la buena salud sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D